# How to retrieve an image from the selected GridView row

Tags: gridview

I want find another proper approach on how to retrieve a picture or image from a selected row in XtragridControl gridview to picture box in the form.

This is the scenario.

I have a ribbon control with multiple buttons, the first button opens the Customer data, where you find a user control with 2 buttons first button which open the customer form to add new customer and the second button opens the edit customer form where u edit customer after selecting a particular customer from the grid, i want a simpler approach that can allow me to retrieve the image or photo of the customer along with all other information.

Find below a sample of my code :

```csharp
// this my class Holding Field from table in database 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

   namespace YoungWoman
   {
       public static class GetRowData
      {      

   public static int LesseeId;

   public static byte image; // 



   public static string LesseeName;
   public static string LesseeLastName;
   public static string PassportNo;
   public static string IDNo;
   public static DateTime BirthDate;
   public static string Gender;
   public static string Country;
   public static string City;
   public static string Province;
   public static string LesseePostalCode;
   public static string MobileNo;
   public static string HomePhoneNo;
   public static string TutorName;
   public static string TutorLastName;
   public static string AddressTutor;
   public static string AddressLessee;
   public static string TutorPhoneNo;
   public static string TutorEmail;




   }
  }


   // this user control containing the XtragridControl and how i retrieve values from the grid to get the form populated 


      private void EditLesseeFrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lesseefrm Lessee = new Lesseefrm(Utils.Formtype.edit, 1);
        Lessee.LesseeEventHandler += new EventHandler(RefreshLesseeGrid);
        Lessee.RefreshLabeslEvent += new EventHandler(RefreshingLabels);


        GetRowData.LesseeId = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseeId"));
        //GetRowData.LesseePic = ByteImageConve(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseePic")); // this line of code return an error 
        GetRowData.LesseeName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseeName"));
        GetRowData.LesseeLastName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"LesseeLastName"));
        GetRowData.PassportNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle,"PassportNo"));
        GetRowData.Gender = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Gender"));
        GetRowData.Province = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Province"));
        GetRowData.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "BirthDate"));
        GetRowData.City = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "City"));
        GetRowData.Country = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Country"));
        GetRowData.MobileNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "MobileNo"));
        GetRowData.HomePhoneNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "HomePhoneNo"));
        GetRowData.IDNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "IDNo"));
        GetRowData.AddressLessee = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "AddressLessee"));
        GetRowData.AddressTutor = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "AddressTutor"));
        GetRowData.LesseePostalCode = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "LesseePostalCode"));
        GetRowData.TutorName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorName"));
        GetRowData.TutorLastName = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorLastName"));
        GetRowData.TutorPhoneNo = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorPhoneNo"));
        GetRowData.TutorEmail = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "TutorEmail"));

        Lessee.ShowDialog();
    }


       // this the form to receive the values from the grid to update



            if (formtype == Formtype.edit && Lesseeid > 0)
            {



                LesseeIdtextEdit.Enabled = false;
                ClearBtnlayoutControlItem26.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.LayoutVisibility.Never;
                SaveBtn.Text = "&Edit";
                SaveBtn.Image = Resources.brush_16;
                this.Text = string.Format(" Edit Lessee Information - YW Residence ");

                LesseeIdtextEdit.Text = Convert.ToInt32(GetRowData.LesseeId).ToString();
                txtName.Text = GetRowData.LesseeName;
                txtLAstname.Text = GetRowData.LesseeLastName;
                txtPassport.Text = GetRowData.PassportNo;
                txtID.Text = GetRowData.IDNo;
                GendercomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem = GetRowData.Gender;
                DobdateEdit.DateTime = GetRowData.BirthDate;
                CountrycomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem = GetRowData.Country;
                txtProvince.Text = GetRowData.Province;
                txtCity.Text = GetRowData.City;
                txtPostalCode.Text = GetRowData.LesseePostalCode;
                LesseememoEdit1.Text = GetRowData.AddressLessee;
                txtMobile.Text = GetRowData.MobileNo;
                txtHomePhone.Text = GetRowData.HomePhoneNo;
                txtTutorName.Text = GetRowData.TutorName;
                txttutorLastname.Text = GetRowData.TutorLastName;
                tutorAddresstxt.Text = GetRowData.AddressTutor;
                txtTutorMobile.Text = GetRowData.TutorPhoneNo;
                txtEmail.Text = GetRowData.TutorEmail;



            }


       and this how i save before proceeding to any update 



             private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (formtype == Formtype.add)
        {
            if (txtPassport.Text.Length >= 8)
            {
                dxErrorProvider1.ClearErrors();



                try
                {

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    PicBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);

                    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(" insert into LesseeYW (LesseePic,LesseeName,LesseeLastName,PassportNo,IDNo,BirthDate,Gender,Country,LesseePostalCode,City,Province,MobileNo,HomePhoneNo,TutorName,TutorLastName,AddressTutor,AddressLessee,TutorPhoneNo,TutorEmail)Values(@image1,@name,@LastName,@pass1,@IDno,@DOB,@Gender,@Country1,@Postal,@City,@Province,@Mobile,@Phone,@Tname,@TLast,@address1,@address2,@Tphone,@Email)", conne);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GetRowData.LesseeId);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image1", Pic_arr);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLAstname.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass1", txtPassport.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDno", txtID.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DobdateEdit.DateTime);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GendercomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country1", CountrycomboBoxEdit.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postal", txtPostalCode.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", txtProvince.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtHomePhone.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tname", txtTutorName.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TLast", txttutorLastname.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", tutorAddresstxt.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", LesseememoEdit1.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tphone", txtTutorMobile.Text);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);


                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conne.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(" Lessee Data Successfully Added ", " Confirmation Lessee Data ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid PassportNo","Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                dxErrorProvider1.SetError(txtPassport, "Invalid Passport No");

            }


            if (LesseeEventHandler != null)
            {
                LesseeEventHandler(sender, e);
            }

            if (LsEventHandler != null)
            {
                LsEventHandler(sender, e);
            }

            if (SelectEventHandler != null)
            {
                SelectEventHandler(sender, e);
            }
            if (LabelsEvent != null)
            {
                LabelsEvent(sender, e);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a strongly typed dataset or EF, to bind the content of the table to your grid.
Then you wouldn't need to think so much about loading and saving your data.

Since you are using devexpress, I would also use DataLayoutControl to bind the different fields from your datasource.

You have declared your image as byte, is that a typo?
use byte[] or Image

If you want to use your class, replace your variables with properties, then you can bind them to the gui controls, it is also an all over better design to use properties in classes.